# MYSQL + PHP issue where Firstname

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Guys im having a issue with my mysql php problem ok i want this to pull table information out of my mysql database in it shows up the firstname by the number 10 but i want to add more too it like 10 100 1000 in other numbers how can i do this from this code

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM tvshows
WHERE FirstName='10',100,1000");
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM tvshows WHERE FirstName IN (10,100,1000);
```

You can look here:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/any-in-some-subqueries.html

and here:

http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/subqueries_part_1.html

If you want to select strings, you need to '', ex.:

```
SELECT * FROM tvshows WHERE FirstName IN ('10','100','1000');
```

If Numbers like this:

```
SELECT * FROM tvshows WHERE FirstName IN (10,100,1000);
```

Comment: +1 for referencing platform documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the = for IN

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM tvshows WHERE FirstName IN(10,100,1000);
```

[SQL IN clause documentation](https://www.google.com/search?q=sql%20in&oq=sql%20in&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l3.749j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Answer (score 0):

**The IN operator allows you to specify multiple values in a WHERE clause.**

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM tvshows
WHERE FirstName IN('10','100','1000')");
```

See [Example](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_in.asp)